# How do I write a Stored Procedure that generates a unique identifier? 

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

Please help me with writing the stored procedure that autogenerate the number like...

`ABC0000001`

It should happen for each entry we make through asp.net page. I mean for each time when the page loads it should create this unique number.

Comment: Please update your post to include what you've written so far.

Comment: why on earth would you want a **stored procedure** to generate a unique number for every page request in asp.net?

Comment: Why does it need 'ABC' on the front, what's wrong with a normal identity? If you need an additional code for segregation then store it separately and return it in your view as a concatenation.

Comment: @Cheta, A number "like" 'ABC0000001' is "XYZ0000001" ... You need to at the very least *describe the pattern you're attempting to generate*. **One example does not describe a pattern.**

Comment: Why do you need database for this? Can't you use ASP.NET application variable or session itself to do this?

Comment: At least tell us which database you're using. Everyone appears to be guessing at SQL Server for now. :)

Comment: @Cheta: Do you have anything to say?

Answer (score 2):

I've done similar things for various business objects that need a project number or something along those lines:

```
declare @maxnum int
declare @myNumber @varchar(32) 
select @maxnum = max(columnName) + 1 from theTable
select @myNumber = 'ABC' + replicate('0', 8 - len(@maxnum)) + cast(@maxnum as varchar)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to store this number in the database somewhere? So maybe this is an Insert stored procedure, to add a new page?

You're going to have to store the number somewhere so that the stored procedure knows what the next number should be. So..why not store it as an integer, set it with uniqueidentifier and identity insert - so each row you add you have the next number as the ID.

If you really need it to have 'ABC' on the front, then just add this to the integer in the stored procedure when you return the value.

Answer (score 0):

Create the UDF PADL as below:

```
CREATE function PADL  (@cSrting nvarchar(4000), @nLen smallint, @cPadCharacter nvarchar(4000) = ' ' )
returns nvarchar(4000)
as
      begin
        declare @length smallint, @lengthPadCharacter smallint
        select  @length = datalength(@cSrting)/(case SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@cSrting,'BaseType') when 'nvarchar' then 2  else 1 end) -- for unicode
        select  @lengthPadCharacter = datalength(@cPadCharacter)/(case SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@cPadCharacter,'BaseType') when 'nvarchar' then 2  else 1 end) -- for unicode

        if @length >= @nLen
           set  @cSrting = left(@cSrting, @nLen)
        else
       begin
              declare @nLeftLen smallint,  @nRightLen smallint
              set @nLeftLen = @nLen - @length  -- Quantity of characters, added at the left
              set @cSrting = left(replicate(@cPadCharacter, ceiling(@nLeftLen/@lengthPadCharacter) + 2), @nLeftLen)+ @cSrting
           end

    return (@cSrting)
   end
GO
```

You can use a table to store the current number and get the next number and use the PADL UDF to pad with required number of '0' and then concat the 'ABC' into it.

Answer (score 0):

Example below. You can also add datetime of request to the table, you can also pass in other information you want to store about the request such as referrer, method etc.

```
create table RequestRecords (
  ixRequestRecord int identity primary key,
  sWhatever nvarchar(max) -- anything else you want to store
)

Create proc WebNewRequestEntry(@sWhatever nvarchar(max)
as
begin
   insert RequestRecords(sWhatever) select @sWhatever
   select 'ABC'+right('00000000000000' + cast(@@IDENTITY_INSERT as varchar(10)), 10) as sRequestRecord
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I'd create a "NumberSeries" table, which stores the name of a number series, the minimum number, the maximum number, a prefix (`ABC` in your case) and the current value. Then, for the sake of concurrency, I'd create the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetNextNo]
    @series NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @prefix NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @currvalue BIGINT
DECLARE @maxvalue BIGINT
DECLARE @errmsg NVARCHAR(250)   

-- Find max value for number series
SELECT @prefix = Prefix, @maxvalue = EndValue FROM NumberSeries WHERE Series = @series
IF (@maxvalue IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @errmsg = 'Number series "'+@series+'" does not exist!'
    RAISERROR(@errmsg, 16, 1)
    RETURN
END

-- Create next number
DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE (CurrValue BIGINT)
UPDATE tNumberSeries
SET
    CurrentValue = CurrentValue + 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.CurrentValue INTO @MyTableVar
WHERE
    Series = @series

-- Number series used up?
SELECT TOP 1 @currvalue = CurrValue FROM @MyTableVar    
IF (@currvalue >= @maxvalue)
BEGIN
    SET @errmsg = 'Number series "'+@series+'" is used up!'
    RAISERROR(@errmsg, 16, 1)
    RETURN
END

SET @result = CAST(@currvalue AS NVARCHAR)
IF @prefix IS NOT NULL
    SET @result = @prefix + @result

-- Return prefixed result
SELECT @result AS CurrentValue
RETURN 0

END
```

The `UPDATE/OUTPUT` statement makes sure that the current value is increased in a way that parallel callers receive unique numbers in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a check-[constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491.aspx) to the table containing this field:

```
([ABC_Number] IS NOT NULL AND len([ABC_Number])=(10) AND substring([ABC_Number],(1),(3))='ABC' AND substring([ABC_Number],(4),(7)) like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

On this way you ensure that it's impossible to inject a record with an invalid unique-identifier-format from somewhere.

And a unique-constraint to ensure that a number is not duplicate in the table:

```
[dbo].[_CountAbcNumber]([abc_number])<(2)
```

where _CountAbcNumber is a udf like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[_CountAbcNumber](
    @AbcNumber AS nchar(10)
)

RETURNS int AS BEGIN
    declare @retVal int

   select @retVal = max(occurrences)
   from ( 
        select ABC_NUMBER, count(*) as occurrences
        from dbo.YourTable            
        where ABC_NUMBER = @AbcNumber
        group by ABC_NUMBER
   ) tmp
   return @retVal;
END
```